# Is it Possible to Reduce (Shrink) a Linux Software RAID10 Array?

Tags: raid

I'm trying to shrink a Linux software RAID10 array. I have already shrunk the FS volume. The md volume is 64kb chunks w/ "far" mode. Is it possible to safely shrink the underlying RAID array in someway without having to wipe one drive, copy the data and re-sync?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information please; OS, disk controller, disks, disk layout, partition/volume types etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions have nothing to do with raid array settings. If you can shrink the partition using the tools your OS provides, then you might be able to also change the size of the VD, depending on the raid controller you have

Comment: Sorry, you got one step ahead of me. I didn't mean the physical partition, but the MD array. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: ah, I see now. no, afaik there's no safe way, all you can do is backup>testBackup>rebuild>restore